# Return ActionResult that redirects to another controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller named `LoginController` and `HomeController`. Inside of the `LoginController` I have a `LoginAsync` function that looks like this:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public async Task<ActionResult> LoginAsync(string username, string password)
 {
      ...

      var apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse>(result);
      if (!apiResponse.IsSuccessful)
      {
           return Content(apiResponse.Message);
      }

      ...

      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "Index" });
 }
```

And its called via AJAX in the `LoginAsync` function in the `LoginController`:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#Login').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                     url: "Login/LoginAsync",
                     type: "POST",
                     data: { username: document.getElementById('txtUsername').value, password: document.getElementById('txtPassword').value },
                     async: true,
                     success: function (data) {
                        alert(data);
                    //window.location.href = "Home";
                },
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

For whatever reason, the `return RedirectToAction(...)` line is firing but the page is not redirecting to the home page like I thought it would. What's really confusing me is the Ajax line `alert(data);` is showing the HTML content for the home page - the page I want to redirect to. So after I click the button to trigger the Ajax, instead of going to the home page, it just pops up the HTML for the home page and stays on the login page.

How can I make it so `LoginAysnc` redirects to the HomeController/Index view?

Comment: If you call this with an async javascript function why would you think the browser would then issue a redirect? What you could do is return the url you want to redirect to in the event of failure and handle that in the script call back and then direct the user to that URL. Also the `alert` message you are observing makes perfect sense, the servers redirect returns the html for the page you want to go to but you called it from $.ajax so that html is a part of the response in the variable `data`

Comment: The standard/proper way to wire this up is to return status code 200 if authentication was successful. The script can then set `window.location.href` to redirect where you want it to. On failure return a different status code with some information and handle it accordingly. Do not try to issue the redirect from the server side.

Comment: @Igor "Do not try to issue the redirect from the server side." Oh - that's exactly what I was trying to do. I thought that was the correct way. I thought `RedirectToAction` would handle that. I did have the redirect working from the front end (notice the commented out ajax section). So thats the correct way?

Comment: You can return it as a redirect response if you want, but you would need to conditionally check for a 302 status code and then change `window.location` respectively to cause the browser to actually load the new page. This will not happen automatically for you. `XMLHttpRequest` (what's actually used for "AJAX") is a thin client. it does nothing with responses it receives. That's all on you.

Comment: Alright thanks guys - handling the redirect via `window.location` if the response is valid worked perfectly. I did not know you don't do redirects from the server side so I think that's why I was so confused.